# Find Regexp debug to the first numeric character

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to retrieve a string of text to the beginning of my first character digital .it may be that there was a line break .

I found a java regex syntax but it does not work on GS google script!

I attens your advice.

---

Prenom NOM

33 Ans

### Le 03/03/2015

```
function demoReplaceClick() {

//  var regexp = /............... [0-9] {1,3}/g;
//  var regexp = /^[0-9]$/g;
  var regexp = /^[A-Z]?[0-9] {1}/g;
  var regexp = /\w.{1,30}Ans$/g; //this don't work on "GS" Google Script


  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getText();
  var result = regexp.exec(doc);
  var FirstnameSecondname = new RegExp(result,"g"); //Extrait 2 Premiers Chiffres

  Logger.log(FirstnameSecondname);
 }
```

Comment: 1) There are 2 "regexp" variables, ceck them please 2) The regex to get the age is not correct, it must be `\d+(?=\sAns)` (https://regex101.com/r/gI2fV9/1) Does that suffice?

Comment: Thanks stribizhev ,it's work to find numeric in front of "Ans" et \d+(?=\sAns) g   for multiple ocurences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about /[^0-9]*/g? That would match everything except numbers, so it should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks SGD . I tried your regex but he give me only the first word before Ex Prenom NOM 33 Ans  /  Here the results is NOM

Comment: SGD thank you . I tried your regex but it gives me only the first word before the sequence numbers (if presence of 2 words / Yes .A single word : no) ???: Ex named 33 Years / Here are the results
 Positive point: many considered the newline / n

I want to retrieve all the chain lying before a numeric string .it may be spaces, hyphen, apostrophe

Comment: works beautifully
Thank you very much SGD
I'd made ​​a mistake in copy / paste : an extra space behind the slash
regex is / [^ 0-9] * / g and not / _[^ 0-9] * / g

Comment: Just another regex .I want to find  the string between <<...>> in a text ,beginig <<    and finshing by  >> .

Comment: If you can assume that there is no ">" in the string then you can match /<<[^>]*>>/g. Note that this would also match the leading and trailing escape characters, that can potentially be fixed using matching groups.

Comment: to much .. congratulations    / << [^>] * >> / g